# What is the best way to detect mark on an image? OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, computer-vision

I've been trying to detect some mark on image. I used matchShapes and matchTemplate functions of OpenCV to detect symbols "X", "O", "+", even triangle but i faced too small accuracy :(
Sometimes it detects correctly.
Sometimes it detects small pieces of an image, like a small dot or dash instead of triangle or "X" symbol.

Here is the source code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat src;
    Mat sample;
    Mat circle;
    int idx = 0;
    int ind_min;
    double ret;
    double min = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

    src = imread("triangle.jpg", 0); // Example
    sample = imread("tri4.jpg", 0); // Photo to compare with example
    adaptiveThreshold(sample, sample, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 51, 10);
    threshold(src, src, 140, 255, 1);

    Mat dst2 = Mat::zeros(sample.rows, sample.cols, CV_8UC3);

    src = src > 1;
    sample = sample > 1;

    namedWindow("Source", 1);
    imshow("Source", src);
    namedWindow("Sample", 1);
    imshow("Sample", sample);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours; //Contour of an example
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours2; //Contours of a photo
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy2;
    findContours(src, contours, hierarchy,
        CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    findContours(sample, contours2, hierarchy2,
        CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    //Matching example contours[0] with contours of the photo contours2[idx].
    //Comparing output of matchShapes function, the lower is better. 
    for (; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy2[idx][0])
    {
        ret = matchShapes(contours[0], contours2[idx], CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1, 0.0);
        if (ret < min && ret > 0)
        {
            min = ret;
            ind_min = idx;
        }
    }
    Scalar color(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255);
    drawContours(dst2, contours2, ind_min, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy2);
    namedWindow("Components", 1);
    imshow("Components", dst2);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

What is the best symbol to detect as a mark? And what is the easiest opencv solution with good accuracy?

Comment: Without an example image it is impossible to answer this question. Upload some examples using a free image sharing service (since you don't have enough reputation to add an image to your question).

Comment: http://imgur.com/HaMc1ph,pmuM54f - source image, http://imgur.com/HaMc1ph,pmuM54f#1 - photo

Comment: Your target image clearly has the model in it but it has a lot of distortion. MatchTemplate won't be able to help you there. You seem to be new with image processing, I suggest you read a little bit more about the subject before you go forward and practice with easier problems.

Answer (score 2):

If accuracy is an issue, make sure the scale and projection of the marker are close enough to the image you want to compare. You can **scale** the image to help matching.

Use a feature detector like **SIFT** (or SURF) and a feature matcher like **FLANN** (or even bruteforce) to get the best results.
Also, try to **reduce noise** as much as possible to have more accurate feature detection (Gaussian filter or denoising functions).